# gwt-2.7.0 upgrade - GWT build Error 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImpl' cannot be abstract

Tags: gwt

```
[java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.java'
[java]       [ERROR] Line 64: Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImpl' cannot be abstract
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

.

```
   java.util.Set
 [java]                                                                                                                                                                                                    Verifying instantiability
 [java]                                                                                                                                                                                                       java.util.LinkedHashSet<?>
 [java]                                                                                                                                                                                                          [WARN] Checking all subtypes of Object which qualify for serialization
 [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellBasedWidgetImpl.java'
 [java]       [ERROR] Line 46: Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImpl' cannot be abstract
```

Error while building gwt project war with ant (gwt-2.7.0). Project runs okay in Super Dev Mode. War builds without any error with gwt-2.5.0

Comment: might be issue with dependency jars.. please share full error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove opera permutation from gwt.xml

```
    <extend-property name="user.agent" values="opera" />
```

gwt-2.7.0 does not support opera permutation